# SQL consult joining two tables, group and order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that i need to consult with one query, i have the `Participante` table that will store some data from the user and the `ParticipanteResultado` that will store the answers of that user.

Table `Participante`

```
participanteID,
**other fields**
```

Table `ParticipanteResultado`

```
participanteResultadoID,
participanteID,
tipo,
quantidadeValidas
```

My `ParticipanteResultado` table can have around 10 results per user, which will be different on the `tipo` that can be (A, B, C, D...).

```
participanteResultadoID participanteID tipo quantidadeValidas
4                       88              S   5
5                       88              E   5
6                       88              A   2
7                       88              I   1
8                       94              S   2
9                       94              E   3
10                      94              A   2
11                      94              I   1
12                      98              S   0
13                      98              E   0
14                      98              A   0
15                      98              I   0
```

What i need is to display the user data and his best result. By best result i mean the result that have the highest value on `quantidadeValidas` field.

My problem is, in the example i gave of the `ParticipanteResultado` data i have the user `88` with a tie and i need to bring those two values, they can be in the same column like (S, E).

If he doesn't have any valid answer, `quantidadeValidas = 0`, i don't need his `tipo`.

UPDATE
Got some of the work done with some help of @lrb

```
SELECT participanteID, nome, email, unidadeCE, telefone, 
tipo =
    SUBSTRING((
        SELECT  ', ' + CAST(tipo AS NVARCHAR(10))
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT pr.tipo, pr.participanteID
            FROM ParticipanteResultado pr
            WHERE pr.participanteID = p.participanteID AND quantidadeValidas > 0             
        )AS X2                      
        ORDER BY tipo FOR XML PATH( '' )
    ), 3, 1000 )
FROM Participante p;
```

It outputs:

```
participanteID  nome            email               unidadeCE   telefone         tipo
88              teste teste     teste@teste.com.br  41925       (11) 11111-1111  E, S
94              teste teste     teste@teste.com     36433       (11) 11111-1111  E, I, S
```

But in the case of `participanteID 94` i should only print E as `tipo` since its the highest value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
SELECT DISTINCT pr.tipo, pr.participanteID
FROM ParticipanteResultado pr
WHERE pr.participanteID = p.participanteID AND quantidadeValidas > 0
```

as your innermost SELECT, you can use this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES pr.tipo
FROM ParticipanteResultado pr
WHERE pr.participanteID = p.participanteID AND quantidadeValidas > 0
ORDER BY quantidadeValidas DESC
```

This subquery was first suggested (only without the `AND quantidadeValidas > 0` bit) in the now deleted answer by [Paul Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27968/paul-williams)<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>However, Paul did not use a FOR XML middle tier, and without it his solution would break on rows with ties (which he may have realised eventually and that is probably why he has deleted his answer).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dense Rank` with `Window function`

```
SELECT participanteID,
       nome,
       email,
       unidadeCE,
       telefone,
       tipo
FROM   (SELECT Dense_rank()OVER(partition BY a.participanteID ORDER BY quantidadeValidas) Rnk,
               *
        FROM   Participante a  join ParticipanteResultado b on a.participanteID = b.participanteID) P
WHERE  Rnk = 1
```

Comment: It didn't work since they are two different tables and u are using only one

Comment: @Terkhos - Updated check now. remove * and select required columns

Comment: All the results came as NULL

SELECT participanteID,
       nome,
       email,
       unidadeCE,
       telefone,
       tipo
FROM   (SELECT Dense_rank()OVER(partition BY a.participanteID ORDER BY quantidadeValidas) Rnk,
               a.nome,
      a.email,
      a.tipo,
      a.participanteID,
      a.unidadeCE,
      a.telefone
        FROM   Participante a  join ParticipanteResultado b on a.participanteID = b.participanteID) P
WHERE  Rnk = 1

Comment: @Terkhos Add sample data of your table and the expected output

Comment: Now it works but i need the data to be grouped, i'm edit my question with the data